# How does 的に work in this clause: 「よくなるしかない的にいいこと 」

Tags: grammar, adverbial

I normally see 的に at the end of words and I understand them but I can't seem to understand this one

> よくなるしかない的にいいこと

Comment: It is probably read as まと here to mean goal, not as you may be used to seeing it.

Comment: If I guessed correctly, this is probably a kind of oxymonoric rhetoric, but it's hard to explain this without enough context. Please [read this](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2189/5010) and add several sentences around this.

Comment: Is the line from [this 小説](https://syosetu.org/novel/197938/13.html)? "「私は[凶]{きょう}だー」「いやでもそれあれでしょー、こっから[良]{よ}くなるしかない[的]{てき}にいいことでしょー」" where they're talking about おみくじ.

Comment: Ah yes it is...